# ExtJS: Dynamically add item to viewport region

Tags: javascript, extjs

Let's say I have a JS in one file that creates a `Viewport`:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [
        {
            region: 'center'
        }, 
        ...
    ]
});
```

Now let's say I have another JS file that loads subsequently with this component definition:

```
{
    contentEl: 'content',
    height: '100%'
}
```

How do I add that component with `contentEl: 'content'` to the `'center'` region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var viewpoert = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border'
});
```

anoter file;

```
var contentEl = Ext.Create('Ext.Something.What.You.Want', {
     region: "center"
});
```

finally:

```
viewport.add(contentEl);
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I don't want to add a contentEl to the viewport, I want to add a contentEl to a region already in the viewport. Make sense?

Comment: May be other solution is what you want: add a panel to region: 'center' and contentEl to that panel?

Answer (score 4):

```
var viewPort = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [
        {
            region: 'center',
            id:'centerViewPortId'
        }
        ]
});

//your second javascript file
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var contentEl = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
        contentEl: 'content',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
viewPort.getComponent('centerViewPortId').add(contentEl);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This link still came up top of the search results for Google, so I thought I'd add another neat solution:

```
var viewPort = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border'
});

//your second javascript file
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var contentEl = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
        contentEl: 'content',
        region: 'center',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
viewPort.add(contentEl);
});
```